# PHP email sending Issue in phpmailer

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmailer

my problem is when i click the submit button it does submit the form and i don't receive any problems on the website or inside of the console.Only changes i made to my code was editing the php part which was creating table i dont know it thats triggers the issue. But somehow i don't receive any mail after i click the submit button. Can you guys please help me through this problem?

```
HTML CODES
    <div class="container contact-form-container text-center">
        <div class="row">
            
            <form method="post" action="php/process.php">
    
            <div class="col-12">
                <p class="contact-form-title">CONTACT US</p>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-12 contact-form-col">
                <div class="contact-form-div">
                    <label class="contact-form-label" for="first-name">First Name <span class="contact-form-span">*</span></label>
                    <input class="contact-form-input" type="text" id="first-name" name="first-name" required>
                </div>
                
                <div class="contact-form-div">
                    <label class="contact-form-label" for="surname">Surname <span class="contact-form-span">*</span></label>
                    <input class="contact-form-input" type="text" id="surname" name="surname" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-12 contact-form-col">
                <div class="contact-form-div">
                    <label class="contact-form-label" for="email">Email <span class="contact-form-span">*</span></label>
                    <input class="contact-form-input" type="text" id="email" name="email" required>
                </div>
                
                <div class="contact-form-div">
                    <label class="contact-form-label" for="phone-number">Phone Number <span class="contact-form-span">*</span></label>
                    <input class="contact-form-input" id="tel" type="text" id="phone-number" name="phone-number" placeholder="(+1) 123 456 789" required>
                </div>
            </div>  
            
            <div class="col-12 contact-form-col">
                <div class="contact-form-div">
                    <label class="contact-form-label" for="country">Country <span class="contact-form-span">*</span></label>
                    <input class="contact-form-input" type="text" id="country" name="country" value="United States" required>
                </div>
                
                <div class="contact-form-div">
                <label class="contact-form-label" for="state">State / Province  <span class="contact-form-span">*</span></label>
                <select class="contact-form-select" name="state" required>
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select State</option>
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                    <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                    <option value="NY">New York</option>
                    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>  
    
            <div class="col-12 contact-form-col">
                <div class="contact-form-div">
                    <label class="contact-form-label" for="company-name">Company Name</label>
                    <input class="contact-form-input" type="text" id="company-name" name="company-name">               
                </div>
                
                <div class="contact-form-div">
                    <label class="contact-form-label" for="how-did-you-hear-about-us">How Did You Hear About Us?</label>
                    <input class="contact-form-input" type="text" id="how-did-you-hear-about-us" name="how-did-you-hear-about-us">
                </div>
            </div>  
    
            <div class="col-12 contact-form-col">
                <div class="contact-form-div">
                    <label class="contact-form-label" for="tell-us-about-your-project">Tell Us About Your Project?</label>
                    <textarea class="contact-form-textarea" id="tell-us-about-your-project" name="tell-us-about-your-project" rows="5" cols="90%"></textarea>             
                </div>
            </div>  
    
            <div class="submit-button-div">
                <div class="col-6 contact-form-col">
                    <div class="contact-form-div">
                        <input class="contact-form-submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit">   
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
    
        </form>
    
        <?php
    if (isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['status'])) {
        if ($_GET['email'] == 'send') {
            if ($_GET['status'] == 'ok') {
                echo '<script>';
                echo 'if (!localStorage.getItem("refreshed")) {';
                echo '  localStorage.setItem("refreshed", "true");';
                echo '  alert("Email send success");';
                echo '  window.location.reload();';
                echo '}';
                echo '</script>';
            } elseif ($_GET['status'] == 'no') {
                echo '<script>alert("Email send error");</script>';
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <script>
    var inputEl = document.getElementById('tel');
    var goodKey = '0123456789+ ';
    
    var checkInputTel = function(e) {
      var key = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
      var start = this.selectionStart,
        end = this.selectionEnd;
    
      var filtered = this.value.split('').filter(filterInput);
      this.value = filtered.join("");
    
      /* Prevents moving the pointer for a bad character */
      var move = (filterInput(String.fromCharCode(key)) || (key == 0 || key == 8)) ? 0 : 1;
      this.setSelectionRange(start - move, end - move);
    }
    
    var filterInput = function(val) {
      return (goodKey.indexOf(val) > -1);
    }
    
    inputEl.addEventListener('input', checkInputTel);
    </script>
    
    <script>
    var uploadField = document.getElementById("file-size");
    
    uploadField.onchange = function() {
        if(this.files[0].size > 50000000){
           alert("File is too big!");
           this.value = "";
        };
    };
    </script>


PHP CODES

    enter code here<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    try {
        $html = "<table>";

        $html .= '<tbody>';
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<th>Full Name: </th>';
        $html .= '<td>' . $_POST['first-name'] . ' ' . $_POST['surname'] . '</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';

        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<th>Email: </th>';
        $html .= '<td>' . $_POST['email'] . '</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';

        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<th>Phone Number: </th>';
        $html .= '<td>' . $_POST['phone-number'] . '</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';

        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<th>Country: </th>';
        $html .= '<td>' . $_POST['country'] . '</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';

        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<th>State / Province: </th>';
        $html .= '<td>' . $_POST['state'] . '</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';

        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<th>Company Name: </th>';
        $html .= '<td>' . $_POST['company-name'] . '</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';

        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<th>How Did You Hear About Us?: </th>';
        $html .= '<td>' . $_POST['how-did-you-hear-about-us'] . '</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';

        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<th>Tell Us About Your Project: </th>';
        $html .= '<td>' . nl2br($_POST['tell-us-about-your-project']) . '</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';

        // Add code for handling file attachment here

        $html .= '</tbody>';
        $html .= "</table>";

        $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER | SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
        $mail->Host = 'localhost';
        $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = false;
        $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;

        $mail->setFrom('demo@demo.com', 'no-name');
        $mail->addAddress('demo@demo.com');
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);

        $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $mail->Body = $html;

        $response = $mail->send();

        if ($response) {
            header('Location: https://www.demo.com/');
        } else {
            echo $response;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: What does the SMTPDebug output tell you about what happened to the email?

Comment: How can i check that?

Comment: If your PHPMailer code is running, it should be making lots of noise on your web page. If you don't see anything, the code may not be running at all.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way related to Javascript or HTML? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution

The Code Before

```
 $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
```

The New Code

```
$mail->Subject = $_POST['New Mail From Website'];
```

I think google was blocking it because of the title. At the moment its working.

Comment: That sounds pretty strange - your initial code does not contain any field named `New Mail From Website`. Can you explain further why this change resolve the initial problem?

Comment: try using mailsnag.com or a similar service for testing. it will help you figure out is the issue in your app or in your mail server

Answer (score -2):

Have 2 thing in mind.

First, you need to check that your display_errors and error_reporting in php.ini are set currently, so you can see the errors if they happened.

Second, it's better to test your code in real host or server or at least use Gmail free SMTP server, so you can diagnose that the problem is about code or server.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. It doesn't try to solve the problem, merely offers some debugging tips. Wait till you have 50 reputation, then you can post comments. Until then, you should not mis-use the Answers feature. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, working in any section need at least 20 reputation and new user only can send answer. So if I try to help someone, I just have one way ! It seems a little bad behavior. Don't you think ?

Comment: Privileges have to be earned on the site. It only takes a few ok-ish answers (or questions) to get to 50. Those are the rules. An "answer" which doesn't answer the question isn't really an answer! So it's not useful in that context.